# Remove MediaWiki Pages Before a Certain Date

Tags: mediawiki

I have a rather large MediaWiki database, and I'd like to remove all the pages that haven't been edited since a certain date.

The wiki in question consists of a cut of Wikipedia that was imported when we first created the wiki, and a load of pages we have created ourselves since. We've recently decided that we no longer want the Wikipedia pages, and would therefore like to remove them from the database.

The best method we could think of to do this was to remove all pages that haven't been edited since the original import - the trouble is, we're not sure how to do this.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of pages last edited before (or after) a given date by running an SQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT page_id, page_namespace, page_title
FROM /*prefix*/page
WHERE page_touched < '20110101000000'
```

This lists the ID, namespace number and title of all pages that have not been edited since the beginning of 2011.  (The timestamp format is `'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'`.)  If you configured a table name prefix when you installed MediaWiki, you need to replace `/*prefix*/` above with it.

At this point, there are several things you could do:

- As Joshua C. Lerner suggests, you could [export](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aExport) all the pages you want to keep (either with [Special:Export](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aParameters_to_Special%3aExport) or with `maintenance/dumpBackup.php`) and re-import them into a new database.
- There's also a [maintenance script](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aMaintenance_scripts) named `maintenance/deleteBatch.php` which can be used to delete a bunch of pages as if they'd been deleted in the usual way by an admin.
- Finally, if you're really sure you won't want the pages back, you could just replace the first line of the SQL query above with `DELETE`.  I'd strongly suggest making a backup of your database before you do this.  This will leave some orphaned revisions in the database, but you can get rid of them with the imaginatively named maintenance script `maintenance/deleteOrphanedRevisions.php`.

(A minor issue with the first two methods above is that the export and batch delete scripts all want the pages listed with namespace *names*, while the SQL query returns namespace *numbers*.  It's not that hard to convert one to the other just by search and replace, but it does add an extra step to the process.  Of course, if all the pages you want to delete are in the main namespace, this is not an issue: just add `AND page_namespace = 0` to the query and drop the ID and namespace from the output.)

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be simpler to generate a list of your own articles created since the initial setup (with the Wikipedia cut), export those articles, then re-import them into a newly-initialized MediaWiki database.